# Randomized polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In the following, all the operations and polynomials are defined over a finite field of prime order $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a large prime number, e.g. 128-bits.

The question is related to cryptography, so I'll use an adversary as a bad guy.

---

Let the adversary have two polynomials: $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ of degree $d$. Let the adversary have a set of fixed values: $V: \{v_1,...,v_n\}$. Given the two polynomials, an honest part generates:

$F(x)= P_1+\omega(x)\cdot P_2(x)$

where $\omega(x)$ is a random polynomial (i.e. its coefficients are distributed uniformly at random over the field) of degree $d$.

**Question** 1:  is $F(x)$ a random polynomial?

**Question** 2: What is the probability that the adversary finds $\beta$, such that $F(\beta)=v_i\in V$? I'm not interested in the polynomial's roots  as it is easy for the adversary to find some values like $r$, such that $F(r)=0$. So $\beta$ doe not include the polynomial roots.

---

**Question** 3: In general, what is the probability of guessing $\alpha$, without having a random polynomial $\gamma(x)$ such that $\gamma(\alpha)=v$, where the degree of $\gamma(x)$ is $d$ and $v$ is an arbitrary value?